# Vue SassError: Undefined variable $white when upgrade vuetify to 2.5

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I have a vue project that worked fine with vuetify 1.5

But as announced in vuetify LTS, version 1.5 is no longer supported then i decided to upgrade it to 2.5.

After upgrade vuetify to 2.5, when I build my project, it throw `SassError: Undefined variable` error.

This is my code:

```
// src/assets/scss/app.scss

$white: #fff;
```

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        sassOptions: {
          prependData: "@import '@/assets/scss/app.scss';"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then i call `$white` variable in my vue file:

```
// User.vue

...
<style lang="scss" scoped>
div {
  color: $white;
}
</style>
```

I'm using sass-loader v10.2.0

```
// package.json

"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.10",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.8.55",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "apollo-link-schema": "^1.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "casual-browserify": "^1.5.19-2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "element-ui": "^2.14.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.1",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.0",
    "module": "^1.2.5",
    "pug": "^3.0.1",
    "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.8",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "terser": "^5.5.1",
    "testcafe": "^1.14.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.9",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
    "vue-csv-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vuejs-paginate": "^2.1.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.8",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2",
    "vuex-type-helper": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.13.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.5.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.10.2",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-testcafe": "^0.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^12.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.37.5",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript-eslint-parser": "^22.0.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0"
  }
```

When build project, it throw this error:

```
  error  in ./src/views/adSet/manager.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
[0]
[0] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[0] SassError: Undefined variable.
[0]    ╷
[0] 90 │     color: $white;
[0]    │            ^^^^^^
[0]    ╵
[0]   src/views/adSet/manager.vue 90:12  root stylesheet
[0]
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/User.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-491 14:3-18:5 15:22-499
[0]  @ ./src/views/User.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
[0]  @ ./src/views/User.vue
[0]  @ ./src/router/index.ts
[0]  @ ./src/main.ts
[0]  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.4:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
[0]
```

What went wrong with my code? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Just to help diagnose: Are you able to use `$white` in a standard scss file without getting that error?

Comment: I cannot use this variable from any where.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that vuetify 2.5 cannot work with node-sass. After remove node-sass and install sass, I change vue.config.js to below, and every thing working fine.

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: "@import '@/assets/scss/app.scss';"
      }
    }
  }
}
```